# Adding pem key to jenkins box

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have a jenkins box, I have ssh in to it and from there I want to access one of the Ec2 instance in AWS, I tried ssh -i "mykeyname.pem" ec2-user@DNSname  but It throws me an error "Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)".
I have the PEM file of the EC2 instance I want to connect. But is there any way I can ssh in to the instance..?

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible reasons.

1. Default user name is not "ec2-user"

   - Please check your using image "jenkins box".
   - If it doesn't use "ec2-user", change user name for ssh commands
2. Your key-pair is incorrect

   - Once you created EC2 instance with correct key-pair, you could access EC2 instance with such commands
   - Please check your using key-pair name

FYI

[Connecting to Your Linux Instance Using SSH](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AccessingInstancesLinux.html)